# Lambda to copy csv files between two folders in S3 exceeding 15 mins

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

What is a a good way to copy a bunch of csv files between two S3 folders using Lambda (that can exceed 15 minutes to run)? Is there a way to do an async call using boto3 and let the lambda be notified once the file copy is done.

Thanks.

Comment: You could also not use Lambda and use an ECS Fargate Task. It's a docker container that starts on a serverless ECS cluster and runs to completion however long it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/) for this. The steps would be something like:

- Have your Lambda function create a new CSV manifest file that describes the copy operations you want to perform, and upload that manifest file to an S3 location somewhere.
- [Create an S3 batch operations job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control.html#S3Control.Client.create_job), pointing it to the CSV manifest file you previously created.

  - As one of the batch job's parameters, configure it to create a completion report, that will be saved to a specific S3 bucket and prefix.
- Have another [Lambda function that is subscribed to S3 new object events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) with the S3 bucket and prefix where the job completion reports will be stored. When this Lambda function is triggered you can then proceed with whatever program logic that needs to occurs after the copy is complete.